# Run-time error 1004, unsure where it is...Where did the file importing go wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

I did my research already and it was something about protected files and what not. I don't think that's the issue here and I am not sure where to pinpoint my issues. I noticed that other people also have the same issue.

Anyways here is the code, when I do the `ws.Range("A:B etc...)` line, the error occurs. Thank you in advance!

```
Sub BucketReview()

    Dim BucketReport As Variant
    Dim BucketReportWB As Workbook
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, MasterList As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Improves Performance
    BucketReport = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    Title:="Select your Fee Report", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")

    If BucketReport <> False Then
       Set BucketReportWB = Application.Workbooks.Open(BucketReport) 
    Else: Exit Sub

    Set wsDest = _
    Workbooks("Test Fee Deduction Plan Master List.xlsm").Sheets("Paste Reporting Here")
    Set ws = BucketReportWB.Worksheets("Queue Status")
    
    ws.Range("A:B,E:E,G:Z,AC:AE").Delete
        
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld A missing worksheet would give a Subscript out of range" error.

Comment: The sheet being protected seems like the most likely cause of the error.

Comment: @Variatus You are absolutely correct. I will delete my comment and upvote Tim Williams.

Comment: Interesting decision. I've upvoted that idea, too :-)

Comment: Just added ws.Unprotect, still isn't working. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is just the huge (really huge!) non-contiguous range in another workbook. Try to split it up with code like this:-

```
Dim Ws      As Worksheet
Dim Rng     As Range

Set Ws = BucketReportWB.Worksheets("Queue Status")

For Each Rng In Ws.Range("A:B,E:E,G:Z,AC:AE").Areas
    Rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next Rng
```

Also consider deleting from right to left instead of left to right (delete the right-most columns before the others).